# After successfully deploying a subgraph via The Graph to Mumbai it suddenly stops working for no apparent reason

Tags: polygon, the-graph, sushiswap, subgraph, graphql

so I have succesfully deployed a subgraph to a fork of the masterchef contract from sushiswap. Before beeing able to sync up properly, the subgraph suddenly throws an error and stops. The error message states:

```
Subgraph instance failed to run: A matching Ethereum network with NodeCapabilities { archive: true, traces: true } was not found.
```

That is very odd to me, there is no `{ archive: true, traces: true }` in my subgraph aswell as mumbai beeing written properly in my subgraph.yaml. I cannot figure out how to make my subgraph run succesfully on mumbai testnet. Can anyone help me with that error, since I havent found a good solution on the internet to that problem.

For additional information here is my subgraph.yaml file:

```
specVersion: 0.0.3
description: Masterchef
schema:
  file: ./schema.graphql
dataSources:
  - kind: ethereum/contract
    name: MasterChef
    network: mumbai
    source:
      address: "0xa41D586530BC7BC872095950aE03a780d5114445"
      abi: MasterChef
      startBlock: 38449425
    mapping:
      kind: ethereum/events
      apiVersion: 0.0.4
      language: wasm/assemblyscript
      entities:
        - MasterChef
        - History
        - Pool
        - PoolHistory
        - User
      abis:
        - name: MasterChef
          file: ../../node_modules/@sushiswap/core/build/abi/MasterChef.json
        - name: Factory
          file: ../../node_modules/@sushiswap/core/build/abi/UniswapV2Factory.json
        - name: Pair
          file: ../../node_modules/@sushiswap/core/build/abi/UniswapV2Pair.json
        - name: ERC20
          file: ../../node_modules/@sushiswap/core/build/abi/ERC20.json
      eventHandlers:
        - event: Deposit(indexed address,indexed uint256,uint256)
          handler: deposit
        - event: EmergencyWithdraw(indexed address,indexed uint256,uint256)
          handler: emergencyWithdraw
        - event: OwnershipTransferred(indexed address,indexed address)
          handler: ownershipTransferred
        - event: Withdraw(indexed address,indexed uint256,uint256)
          handler: withdraw
      callHandlers:
        - function: add(uint256,address,bool)
          handler: add
        - function: set(uint256,uint256,bool)
          handler: set
        - function: massUpdatePools()
          handler: massUpdatePools
        - function: updatePool(uint256)
          handler: updatePool
        - function: setMigrator(address)
          handler: setMigrator
        - function: migrate(uint256)
          handler: migrate
        - function: dev(address)
          handler: dev
      file: ./src/masterchef.ts
```